# Validating data before inserting into database

Tags: php, sql, validation

I want to validate the data contained by Value Objects before inserting into the database (e.g. check that php string is smaller than 255 chars before inserting into a column of type `varchar(255)` or that a string is not inserted in an `int(11)` table column, php date has the correct format etc.).

Is there any framework or easy way to validate data before `SQL INSERT` or `UPDATE` operations?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there some reason this needs to be done in PHP instead of using the features of your database that can maintain referential integrity, detect formatting errors and squawk when there's a problem?

Comment: Well the problem with that is that the DB inserts will trim the input if it's too long, and there will be no way to report that to the user. I want to validate data and then show errors in the view, instead of silently saving trimmed/possibly corrupted data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739900/validating-data-before-inserting-into-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any framework or easy way to
>   validate data before SQL INSERT or
>   UPDATE operations?

php has [validation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) builtin the data [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) package.
I would not advice you to use a complicated framework for this, because it would kill your performance without any real benefits.

Comment: This is the best solution by far. I had no idea there were validation functions built in PHP. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hehe your welcome ;). If this is the best solution, you should accept it ;)(Maybe later after you have more answers??)

Comment: Now an interesting question that came up is how to validate a nested POST array. So say I have an array that contains multiple arrays, do I use filter_input_array recursively or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Figured it out lol. You just do nested arrays and set 'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY for each nested array :)

Comment: Nice :). Thanks for the approval :P